# what are these called <item name="xxxxxxxx,xxxx,xx" and where to find?

Tags: android

hi basically what the title say, I need to know what these are called and where I can find more of them because they dont auto show up in eclipse. I would like to know what i have to work with.

```
<style name="customTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/White</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/TextAppearance.Red.PopupMenu.Large</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Main</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/myListView</item>
</style>
```

i want to know where I can find more things like `android:*textAppearanceLargePopupMenu*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the list of all the attributes here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html